# Sorting after grouping objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Lets say I have the following data:

```
const collection = [
        {
            callId: "1",
            deadline: null
        },
        {
            callId: "1",
            deadline: null
        },
        {
            callId: "3",
            deadline: "2020-04-02T13:37:00.000Z" //assume its a JS date object
        },
        {
            callId: "3",
            deadline: "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z" //assume its a JS date object
        },
        {
            callId: "2",
            deadline: null
        },
        {
            callId: "2",
            deadline: "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z" //assume its a JS date object
        },
    ]
```

I would like to group them by `callId` but have the grouped data sorted by the `deadline`. So the result I want is:

```
const sorted = {
        "3": [
            {
                callId: "3",
                deadline: "2020-04-02T13:37:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                callId: "3",
                deadline: "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z"
            },
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                callId: "2",
                deadline: "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                callId: "2",
                deadline: null
            },
        ],
        "1": [
            {
                callId: "1",
                deadline: null
            },
            {
                callId: "1",
                deadline: null
            },
        ],
    }
```

I tried using `lodash`:

```
const groupedData = _groupBy(collection, 'callId')
const sortedData = _sortBy(groupedData, [function (resultItem) {
        return _map(resultItem, function (value) {
            return value.deadline == null;
        });
    }]);
```

But Im not managing to get the right result:

```
[
[
    {
        "callId": "3",
        "deadline": "2020-04-02T13:37:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "callId": "3",
        "deadline": "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z"
    }
],
[
    {
        "callId": "2",
        "deadline": null
    },
    {
        "callId": "2",
        "deadline": "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z"
    }
],
[
    {
        "callId": "1",
        "deadline": null
    },
    {
        "callId": "1",
        "deadline": null
    }
]
]
```

Comment: do you want to get `sorted`? as object?

Comment: Well sorted by the closest date and grouped by the callId

Comment: you can not sort an object by keys who have index like keys.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the Array based on dates and then use JavaScript's in-built [Array Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

```js
let collection = [
        {
            callId: "1",
            deadline: null
        },
        {
            callId: "1",
            deadline: null
        },
        {
            callId: "3",
            deadline: "2020-04-02T13:37:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            callId: "3",
            deadline: "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            callId: "2",
            deadline: null
        },
        {
            callId: "2",
            deadline: "2020-04-06T08:33:00.000Z"
        },
    ]

 // Sort based on date (Null values will be placed at the last)
 collection = collection.sort((a,b) => {
   if (a.deadline === null) {
     return 1;
   }
   else if (b.deadline === null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return new Date(a.deadline) - new Date(b.deadline)
   }
})
    
 // convert the array to object using reduce method
 const grouped = collection.reduce((a,c) => ({
   ...a,
   // Check if the key already exist,
   // if yes, append the item to the array
   // or create a new array 
   [c.callId]: a[c.callId] ? [...a[c.callId], c] : [c] 
  }), {})
 
 console.log(grouped)
```

### Ordering of Object keys in JavaScript

Properties of an object in JavaScript *do not have an order*. There may appear to be an order in some browsers but the ECMAScript specification defines object property enumeration order as being implementation-specific so you should not assume one browser's behaviour will be the same as another's.

**If order is important to you, use arrays.**

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answer, but this doesnt sort it by the deadline date

Comment: Added sort to my answer. Currently it's placing null at the top, if that's your desired result, then no probs

Comment: Very neat. Upvoted. The only comment from my end: `sort()` mutates source array, so it would be safer to apply that to source array shallow copy (i.e. `[...collection].sort(...`).

Comment: No, but this this doesnt answer my question. Please check in my question the result that Im looking for. Your result sorts the collection back to callId...so it shows 1, 2 , 3

Comment: The order of IDs should be, 3, 2, 1 ... and the data under the id 2 needs to also be sorted to have the object with deadline first.

Comment: JS Objects do not have an order, use array if order is important  to you